# Flash Lite Optimization - attachMovie vs Timeline

Tags: architecture, flashlite

Give us your opinion about how you define a Flash Lite project for a complex application with many different views.

Do you use :
1) attachMovie with each different views in movie clips in the library
unloadMovie to switch to another view
?

2) timeline ... you use gotoAndStop() ?
the main problem of this, is when you use createEmptyMovieClip(),
created movieclips won't be removed when you gotoAndStop() to another keyframe even if it is separated from the previous one.

I tried solution n°2
Timeline becomes fast overloaded.
Moreover, I learn that you need to put many empty frames to let Flash Lite initialize properly ... if you put 1 keyframe for each view from the very beginning of your timeline, your AS code will be buggy.

I'm now going to use solution n°1.

Tell us about your Flash Lite experience and mobile application architecture.
Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Why not get flash to do the garbage collection?

1. Create an empty MovieClip on the timeline, manually. This will be your "holder" MC.
2. Using actionscript, `attachMovie` all your contents into that holder MC.
3. Now you simply `gotoAndStop` to another frame, to unload all the contents of the holder MC.
4. When you `gotoAndStop` back to this frame, the holder MC should be empty, so back to step 2.